Error with pagination handling in Laravel Livewire - Inquiry
I am currently utilizing Laravel version 11 along with Livewire version 3. I discovered that Livewire can componentize pagination handling using Ajax, which led me to use it. Although the data is displayed correctly during pagination, the list of pages is not being displayed as expected. When navigating to the next page, I encounter a display issue where text such as wire:id="7NLG4TpyWMUcIqHa757S" appears.
class ArticleList extends Component
{
    public $page = 1;
    public $perPage = 2;
    public $articles;
    protected $articlesService;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->fetchArticles();
    }

    public function fetchArticles()
    {
        $this->articlesService = app(ArticlesService::class);
        $this->articles = $this->articlesService->getArticles($this->page, $this->perPage);
    }

    public function gotoPage($page)
    {
        $this->page = $page;
        $this->fetchArticles();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $totalCount = $this->articlesService->getArticlesTotalCount();

        return view('livewire.article-list', [
            'pagination' => compact('totalCount')
        ]);
    }
}

class Pagination extends Component
{
    #[Reactive]
    public $page;
    #[Reactive]
    public $perPage;
    #[Reactive]
    public $total;

    public function mount($page, $perPage, $total)
    {
        $this->page = $page;
        $this->perPage = $perPage;
        $this->total = $total;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $totalPage = ceil($this->total / $this->perPage);

        return view('livewire.pagination', [
            'totalPage' => $totalPage
        ]);
    }
}


<!-- article-list.blade.php -->

<div>
    <h1>Article List</h1>
    <div>
        <ul class="list2">
            @foreach($articles as $article)
                <li>
                    <a href="/articles/detail/{{ $article['id'] }}">
                        {{ $article['body'] }} {{ $article['created_at'] }} {{ $article['user']['name'] }}
                    </a>
                    <a href="/articles/edit/{{ $article['id'] }}">Edit Article</a>
                    <a href="#" wire:click="deleteArticle({{ $article['id'] }})">Delete Article</a>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>

    <livewire:pagination :page="$page" :perPage="$perPage" :total="$pagination['totalCount']"/>
</div>

<!-- pagination.blade.php -->

<div>
    @if ($page > 1)
        <button wire:click="$parent.gotoPage({{ $page - 1 }})">Previous</button>
    @endif

    @for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPage; $i++)
        <button wire:click="$parent.gotoPage({{ $i }})">{{ $i }}</button>
    @endfor

    @if ($page < $totalPage)
        <button wire:click="$parent.gotoPage({{ $page + 1 }})">Next</button>
    @endif
</div>

I have tried adding $parent, #[Reactive], and other elements as per the documentation on the Livewire website, but I still need help to get it to work. I've attached the code below for you to look over.

Welcome to SO. From your the description how the issue materializes for you in the browser, it is likely a configuration problem, albeit the place and which configuration is hard to say. It might be in the blade template, perhaps the comment on top? Cf. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/livewire/livewire-component-tag-showing-weird-strings Please [edit] your question and put in further clarifications. Also please create a minimum reproducible example that suffices to show the error. E.g. write code that demonstrates the issue with a component having a single property only.
